# SVG path element scale transition bug in Firefox browser

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I am trying to animate a svg path element on hover by adding transform scale transition on it.

It works perfectly as intended on chrome, but on firefox it breaks the transition.

Note: It works without transition animation, but transition is needed in this use case.

HTML:

```
<svg viewBox="-1.1 -1.1 2.2 2.2">
  <g>
    <path d="M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.8085734960732691 0.5883951915573843 L 0 0" fill="#ACC6D9" stroke="#ACC6D9" stroke-width="0.01"></path>
    <path d="M -0.8085734960732691 0.5883951915573843 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.8100500340267164 -0.5863607612837983 L 0 0" fill="#93B5D1" stroke="#93B5D1" stroke-width="0"></path>
    <path d="M -0.8100500340267164 -0.5863607612837983 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.3063859980740773 -0.9519073590345604 L 0 0" fill="#81A8C9" stroke="#81A8C9" stroke-width="0"></path>
    <path d="M 0.3063859980740773 -0.9519073590345604 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.999992891049955 -0.0037706563822101314 L 0 0" fill="#6E9CC1" stroke="#6E9CC1" stroke-width="0"></path>
  </g>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" fill="#393D45"></circle>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
path{
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
path:hover{  
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/tpkjf15b/2/

**Edit:**

Chrome 80 (desired output): [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/w2EhMvV.gifv)

Firefox 74 (broken): [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/66cAcLk.gifv)

Comment: I don't see any difference, also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/74 shows "No changes" under SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird bug, apparently caused by the fractional stroke-width as demonstrated by this reduced case:

```css
path {
  transform: scale(1, 1);  
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
path:hover {  
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
:checked ~ svg path {
  stroke-width: 0.1;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="checkbox"><label for="inp">add stroke</label><br>
<svg viewBox="-2.5 -2.5 10 10" width="300">
    <path d="M0 0 L2.5 0 L0 2.5 Z" fill="#ACC6D9"></path>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" fill="#393D45"></circle>
</svg>
```

So for your case, since the strokes are set to the same color as the fills, you *may* be able to avoid this bug by redefining your shapes in a way you don't need that *stroke hack*. I guess you used it to avoid antialiasing artifacts, but instead of such an hack, you'd be better using integer coordinates when possible, or maybe simply using a `viewBox` that would allow stroke-width to be `1` could work.

Also, I didn't checked if this bug has already been referenced, but I can still reproduce on Nightly 76, so you might want to open an issue on Mozilla's bugzilla.

Comment: Changed the way "d" attribute is generated using this article: https://josephkhan.me/creating-a-svg-pie-chart-html5/
Thanks for indicating the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to write css `transform: translate3d(0px,0px,1px) scale(1);` property on `path` before `hover` and `with hover` need to write something like `transform: translate3d(0px,0px,1px) scale(1.1);`
Finally `transform: translateZ(1px);` make it run perfectly in FF.
Works too: `transform: translate3d(0px,0px,1px);`

I hope this will help you lot.

```css
path{
  transform: translate3d(0px,0px,1px) scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
path:hover{  
  transform: translate3d(0px,0px,1px) scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-1.1 -1.1 2.2 2.2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="backface-visibility: hidden;">
  <g>
    <path d="M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.8085734960732691 0.5883951915573843 L 0 0" fill="#ACC6D9" stroke="#ACC6D9" stroke-width="0.01"></path>
    <path d="M -0.8085734960732691 0.5883951915573843 A 1 1 0 0 1 -0.8100500340267164 -0.5863607612837983 L 0 0" fill="#93B5D1" stroke="#93B5D1" stroke-width="0"></path>
    <path d="M -0.8100500340267164 -0.5863607612837983 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.3063859980740773 -0.9519073590345604 L 0 0" fill="#81A8C9" stroke="#81A8C9" stroke-width="0"></path>
    <path d="M 0.3063859980740773 -0.9519073590345604 A 1 1 0 0 1 0.999992891049955 -0.0037706563822101314 L 0 0" fill="#6E9CC1" stroke="#6E9CC1" stroke-width="0"></path>
  </g>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" fill="#393D45"></circle>
</svg>
```